# Predicting V8's Math.random() truncated outputs

Tags: web-application, exploit, random

i'm doing a research & working around **Math.random()** like a month ago.
Math.random() uses **XORSHIFT128+**, so, if we can get the state of the PRNG, it'll be easy to predict future outputs.

It is public knowledge that **Math.random() isn't a CSPRNG**, quoting Mozilla's JS References :

> Note: Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security.

Anyways, we all know we can **guess Math.random() future outputs by getting 3-4 consecutive outputs.**

Here's a github repo about that ->
https://github.com/PwnFunction/v8-randomness-predictor/tree/main

[And here's another repo about the same topic (This even doesn't need consecutive outputs)](https://github.com/XMPPwocky/nodebeefcl)

At this point, everything is very nice, but when we come to the **Practical & Real world aspect**, the things get really hard.
In a practical scenario, the app's don't leak raw Math.random() outputs, right?

Let's imagine we have a NodeJS back-end that generates "random" numbers in a specific range with **this function** :

```
function RandomInt(min, max) {
    let res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return res;
}
```

After defining that function, let's suppose **the server uses that function like this** and retrieves the data to the client :

```
//Let's generate some random values in different ranges
var randomValuesTest = {
    randomVal1:RandomInt(250,300),  
    randomVal2:RandomInt(0,900),
    randomVal3:RandomInt(300,500),  
    randomVal4:RandomInt(0,800),    
    randomVal5:RandomInt(500,900),  
    randomVal6:RandomInt(0,800),    
    randomVal7:RandomInt(0,900) 
};

return randomValuesTest;
```

[After googling three consecutive days, i just reached a guy that made a work-around for this using Python and Z3](https://github.com/d0nutptr/v8_rand_buster)

I have zero Python knowledge, i tried to adapt the code but i haven't achieved it. So i come with a **variety of questions and problems**:

How i can adapt this script to solve this kind of problem?

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is a pure programming question and that's why it is off-topic on Security SE.